# Combination of two Mono with condition

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to combine result form two `Mono` based on some condition. Both `Mono` are results of `WebClient` calls:

- The first one is a single call expecting fast response.
- The second one is a combination of several calls with a slow response.

The idea to "cancel" the second `Mono` if result from the first one satisfies some condition to save time and avoid unnecessary network calls. If the first's `Mono` result is not enough `zip` it with the second `Mono`.

A Kotlin code sample to explain my idea:

```
fun getResult(): Mono<Result> {

    val trivialResultMono: Mono<Result> = webClient.getResult()

    val nonTrivialResultMono: Mono<Result> = webClient
            .getResult()
            .flatMap { webClient.getResult1(it) }
            .flatMap { webClient.getResult2(it) }
            .flatMap { webClient.getResult2(it) }

    //here I need to check if trivial result satisfies some condition,
    //for example trivialResult.size > 5 if it's true I just return
    //trivialResultMono from getResult() function, 
    //it it's false something like this:
    return Mono.zip(trivialResultMono, nonTrivialResultMono) { trivialResult, nonTrivialResult ->
        trivialResult + nonTrivialResult
    }

}
```

UPDATE:

To be more clear let's say that trivialResult comes in 1 second, nonTrivialResult in 2 seconds. I want to get my final result in 1 second in case of `trivialResult.size > 5` and in 2 seconds otherwise.

Using just `Mono.zip(trivialResultMono, nonTrivialResultMono)` I will always get my final result in 2 seconds.

Using `filter + switchIfEmpty` it will take 1 second if `trivialResult.size > 5` and 3 seconds otherwise. Please correct me if I wrong.

Comment: Given that the first call is quick, can you not simply wait for it to complete before filtering out the inappropriate result and switching to the second call?

Comment: Let's assume that the second call is 1,5 times longer than the first. In this case this solution is not so optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter your `trivialResultMono` and apply `switchIfEmpty` operator

```
return trivialResultMono
        .filter(trivialResult -> trivialResult.size > 5)
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.zip(...))
```

Update for `merge` approach:

```
Mono<Result> zipResultMono = Mono.zip...

return Flux.merge(
        trivialResultMono.map(trivialResult -> Tuples.of(1, trivialResult)),
        zipResultMono.map(zipResult -> Tuples.of(2, zipResult)))
        .filter(tuple ->
                (tuple.getT1().equals(1) && tuple.getT2().size > 5) ||
                        tuple.getT1().equals(2))
        .next()
        .map(Tuple2::getT2);
```

You could skip converting to the Tuple2 if zipResult always has size more then 5

Comment: Looks like a solution but in case of trivialResult.size <= 5 time to get result will be longer than just `zip` without filter and switch.

Comment: You could use `trivialResult.cache()`. Duration difference shouldn't be critical for almost all systems.

Comment: I mean in this case requests for trivial and non trivial results will be executed not concurrently but in serial way.

Comment: In such case you could use `Flux.merge` then filter and take first result. I have updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with `flatMap` and `map`:

```
trivial.flatMap(trivialResult -> {
  if (trivialResult.size > 5) {
    return Mono.just(trivialResult);
  } else {
    return nonTrivial.map(nonTrivialResult -> trivialResult + nonTrivialResult);
  }
});
```